# Fill Excel Cells via Powershell with custom colors

Tags: excel, powershell, colors, cell, fill

can I fill Excel Cells with with more (custom) colors than the Interior.ColorIndex (56 Colors) provides?

I am using "Interior.ColorIndex" but it provides only 56 different colors.

```
$FormatSheet1.Range("C1").Interior.ColorIndex = 35
```

Answer (score 1):

#### Answer

You can use the [Color](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.interior.color) property to set an RGB colour value:

```
$FormatSheet1.Range("C1").Interior.Color = 8454080
# 8454080 = a sickly yellow-green colour I found
```

#### Additional Info

VBA has an [`RGB()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/rgb-function) function if you need to convert component R, G and B values into an RGB integer:

```vb
? VBA.RGB(192, 255, 128)
 8454080
```

or you can use the PowerShell equivalent expression:

```
PS> $r = 192; $g = 255; $b = 128;
PS> $rgb = $r + ($g * 256) + ($b * 256 * 256);

PS> $FormatSheet1.Range("C1").Interior.Color = $rgb
```

which you could wrap in a simple function if you need to calculate it multiple times in your script:

```
PS> function RGB($r, $g, $b) { $r + ($g * 256) + ($b * 256 * 256) }

PS> RGB -r 192 -g 255 -b 128
8454080

PS> $FormatSheet1.Range("C1").Interior.Color = RGB -r 192 -g 255 -b 128
```

You can also use a [hexadecimal literal](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_numeric_literals?view=powershell-7.4#integer-literals) if you have a HTML / CSS style colour definition:

```
$FormatSheet1.Range("C1").Interior.Color = 0x80FFC0
```

but note that the the order of bytes is BGR, not RGB like CSS colours, so my yellow-green colour in CSS is `#C0FF80` which gets rearranged to `0x80FFC0` above.

Comment: I'd recommend you using hex here.  The web way of writing this sickly yellow-green is RGB: #80FFC0. Excel uses the reverse BGR. Use: `$FormatSheet1.Range("C1").Interior.Color = 0xC0FF80`

Comment: @vbakke - added your comment about html / css colours - thanks.